# How to check mod_headers and mod_expires modules enabled in apache

Tags: apache, apache-config, mod-expires, php, mod-headers

I want to check whether mod_headers and mod_expires modules enabled or not in my server

Is there a way available to list apache enabled/disabled modules using some php function just like we list php information with **phpinfo();** function?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

On Debian:

```
user@machine:~$ /usr/sbin/apache2 -l
```

Most GNU/Linux distros:

```
user@machine:~$ /usr/sbin/httpd -l
```

Ubuntu:

```
user@machine:~$ ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled
```

On Mac OSX:

```
user@mymac:~$ httpd -l
```

On Win 7 (64-bit):

```
C:\Users\myuser>"\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\bin\httpd.exe" -l
```

Try these commands from a terminal window in all but Windows, which will use CMD instead.

Comment: On FreeBSD (and probably other variants): `user@machine:~$ apachectl -M`

Comment: -l only shows compiled modules, what if module is shared??

Answer (score 73):

All the above answers are wrong. Use instead:

`apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES`

or

`apachectl -M`

Comment: CentOS & RHOS versions of those commands are `/usr/sbin/httpd -t -DUMP_MODULES` and `/usr/sbin/httpd -M`

Comment: @Craig London `apachectl` is the control script and it is available in CentOS as well.

Comment: This should be accepted solution for this question.

Answer (score 7):

Some versions of PHP/Apache show all loaded modules in phpinfo() under "Loaded Modules".

Speeve's answer shows compiled in modules (x6 on my system):

```
echo system('/usr/sbin/apache2 -l');
```

You'll also need to see your enabled modules (x36 for me):

```
echo system('ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/');
```

To get the list of disabled modules, run this command then cross off all the enabled modules:

```
echo system('ls /etc/apache2/mods-available/');
```

Comment: The `mods-enabled` directory is pretty specific to Debian and Ubuntu, other distributions and operating systems handle modules differently.

Answer (score 7):

On Ubuntu you can see the list of enabled modules here,

```
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled
```

Comment: and check /etc/apache2/mods-available for a list of available modules; nice and simple

Comment: yup i'll take this ty!