# Why is not cached images?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, caching, bitrix

Using CMS Bitrix. The site root .htaccess file with the following contents:

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(flv|swf|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|css|js|text|bmp|psd)$">         
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=172000"
 Header append Cache-Control "public, no-transform"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 172000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 172000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 172000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 172000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 172000 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 172000 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 172000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 172000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 172000 seconds"
</ifModule>
```

As you can see, for the use of caching headers, expires. So, come on and check https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ - says "Use your browser's cache," and refers to the fact that .jpg and .png file is not set term caching! But the code above shows that the set! What can be wrong?

That's just in case: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=ru&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmuse.ooo%2F

Comment: 1. Is `mod_expires` loaded? 2. Did you restart/reload the apache server?

Comment: @Константин Use solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794566/ to check modules. May be you need to enable them in `httpd.conf`.